# getting "undefined" when i print json array with js

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsp

I want to parse json array it came down from json.jsp, but when i access `parse.js` it displays `undefined`
Here is `parse.js`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('#login').click(function(event) {
                $.get('json.jsp', {
                }, function(responseText) {
                    var myJSONObject1 = responseText;
                    var myJSONObject = JSON.parse(myJSONObject1);
                    var len = myJSONObject.length;
                    var out = "";
                    for (var i = 0;  i < len; i++) {
                         var student = myJSONObject[i];
                         out += "<li>"+student.ircEvent + "<li>" + student.method+"<li>"+student.regex;
                     }
                    document.getElementById("ajaxResponse").innerHTML = out;
                });
            });
        });
```

and my `json.jsp` is,

```
<%
        response.setContentType("plain/text");
        User user = new User("RAM","ram@gmail.com");
        User user1 = new User("Ravi","ravi@gmail.com");
        User user2 = new User("Raghu","raghu@gmail.com");
        List list = new ArrayList();
        list.add(user);list.add(user1);list.add(user2);
        String json = new Gson().toJson(list);
        response.getWriter().write(json);       
    %>
```

when i access  parse.js file, it displays `undefined`

any ideas......

Comment: And what's the raw output of json.jsp?

Comment: [{"RAM":"ram@gmail.com"},{"Ravi":"ravi@gmail.com"},{"Ragu":"ragu@gmail.com"}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use $.ajax and set the `dataType` to `json`. No need to parse anything. jQuery does it for you. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'json.jsp',
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            if (data.length) {
                var ajaxResponse = document.createElement('table'),
                        tbody = document.createElement('tbody');
                for (var i in data) {
                    if (data.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                        var tr = document.createElement('tr'),
                                key = document.createElement('td'),
                                    keyText = document.createTextNode(i),
                                value = document.createElement('td'),
                                    valueText =  document.createTextNode(data[i]);
                                key.appendChild(keyText);
                            tr.appendChild(key);
                                value.appendChild(valueText);
                            tr.appendChild(value);
                        tbody.appendChild(tr);
                    }
                }
                ajaxResponse.appendChild(tbody);
                $("#ajaxResponse").append(ajaxResponse);
            }
            else alert("No data returned!");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Hello one, first of all thanks a lot for reply ...I tried your code  what you sent above...when I include your code it doesn't show anything on page...please give me some more hint of code.. really, I need that snippet very badly at this time....please help me to crack this .....

Comment: Umm, well... What's your JSON output to parse and what element would you like to display it in? I modded the script so it accepts the JSON you posted in the question's second comment and attached it to a HTML node with the ID `ajaxResponse`.

Comment: I created a <div id="ajaxResponse">..to show the json output came from JSP...seems that all is well ...but I am not getting any output ..

Comment: Well, are you getting any return data? If so, what does it look like? I modelled the JavaScript according to your initial JSON string. You have to have some basic knowledge of how to create HTML nodes with JavaScript in order to display the data dynamically.